# Identity Server 3 - extend user timeout to 20 minutes

Tags: identityserver3

I've searched everywhere but still cannot find a clear explanation of the user timeout process for IdentityServer3.  The default seems to be 5 minutes - if a user is idle for 5 minutes, then clicks a menu link, the user gets kicked out.  I need to extend this to 20 minutes.

I understand the cookie has its own settings, and I am ok with the default 10 days...but can someone explain how to extend the client idle time to 20 minutes?

thanks!

Comment: my question has changed a little...I am new and I am still learning how our application uses IdentityServer3, but I have discovered that we are actually storing the refresh_tokens in a DB (DynamoDB on AWS).  I guess the issue is that the call for the refresh is not happening and the user is getting their session terminated after 5 minutes regardless of their activity...they could be working and just get kicked out.

What is the actual process for grabbing the refresh_token from the DynamoDB once the session has expired?